# ILMerge and NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, ilmerge

I know I am not allowed to merge NHibernate to my "commercial" software but what with merging all assemblies required by NHibernate directly to NHibernate.dll?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do that, technically, but in most cases, embedding assemblies as resources is more likely to product working results than is using ILMerge.

Even the author of ILMerge admitted that he might have never written ILMerge if he had known how to do assembly embedding.

Much more detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964905/63225